# Apply single service logic to two similar buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a function in my `ReverseService` service. I am using this `service` in my `controller`. Calling it on `ng-click`. The problem is, I am calling the same function for two `ng-click`s, and hence being applied for both where I want it to be applied for only one (the one that I click). I know why this is happening, but I am not able to come up with a solution. Here is the code.
**HTML**

```
<div id="sidebar" ng-controller="SideCtrl">
            <!-- here goes a static sidebar -->
            <div class="large_3_custom columns">
                <ul class="side-nav side_nav_custom">
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/dashboard.png" alt="">
                        <a href="#">DASHBOARD</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img ng-src="images/company_profile.png" alt="">
                        <a href="#">COMPANY PROFILE</a>
                        <img ng-src="{{images.current}}" ng-click="swapHere();subSec = !subSec" id="arrowRotate">
                    </li>
                    <li ng-show="subSec">
                        <img src="" alt="">
                        <a href="#">SERVICES</a>
                    </li>
                    <li ng-show="subSec">
                        <img src="" alt="">
                        <a href="#">EMPLOYEES</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/statistics.png" alt="">
                        <a href="#">STATISTICS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/reviews.png" alt="">
                        <a href="#">REVIEWS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/tips_advice.png" alt="">
                        <a href="#">TIPS & ADVICE</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/deals.png" alt="">
                        <a href="#">DEALS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/media.png" alt="">
                        <a href="#">MEDIA</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/price_list.png" alt="">
                        <a href="#">BOOKING</a>
                        <img ng-src="{{images.current}}" ng-click="swapHere();bookSec = !bookSec" id="arrowBook">
                    </li>
                    <li ng-show="bookSec">
                        <img src="" alt="">
                        <a href="#">CALENDAR</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/market.png" alt="">
                        <a href="#">MARKET</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/sponser_deal.png" alt="">
                        <a href="#">SPONSOR A DEAL</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="images/extra_services.png" alt="">
                        <a href="#">EXTRA SERVICES</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**Angular**

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.service("ReverseService", function() {
    // service func goes here --
    this.imgSwap = function(images) {
        if (images.current === images.finalImage) {
            images.current = images.initialImage;
        } else if (images.current === images.initialImage) {
            images.current = images.finalImage;
        }
    };
});
myApp.controller("SideCtrl", function($scope, ReverseService) {
    console.log("thomas");
    $scope.myData = {};
    $scope.images = {
        initialImage: "images/prof_arrow1.png",
        finalImage: "images/prof_arrow.png",
        current: "images/prof_arrow1.png"
    };
    $scope.swapHere = function() {
        ReverseService.imgSwap($scope.images);
    };
    $scope.subSec = false;
    $scope.bookSec = false;
});
```

Here is a [Plunker.](http://plnkr.co/edit/ONac8RGNplWrMF6aWAsd?p=preview)

Comment: can you explain, what is being applied for each ng-click.. i can not guess looking at your plunkr

Comment: `myData.swapHere();` method is invoked on ng-click, which inturn call `ReverseService.imgSwap($scope.myData.images);` inside it. See `script.js` in my plunker.

Comment: The plunker and the code here is slightly different. I created it just to make it easier for you to understand how I want it to work. Refer only one.

Comment: I think you'll have to split up your ".images" for the 2 parts. Since you bind both HTML element to the same data, any change in the data forces an update of both parts. If you want to control them separately, you'll need to separate the data used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should isolate the scope for the images value

I have updated the plunk : [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/9edbBKI0M8rdWfe2abCj?p=preview)

what you need to do is a directive with an isolated scope and a controller. (I let you play with the css to put the image correctly aligned):
I created a template (swapimage.html)

```
 <img src="{{displayImage}}" ng-click="imageClicked()">
```

and the directive

```
myApp.directive("swapArrow", function(ReverseService){
  return {
    restrict:'A',
    scope : {
      images :'=',
      toggleValue : '='
    },
    templateUrl:'swapimage.html',
    controller:function($scope, ReverseService){
      $scope.imageClicked = function(){
        ReverseService.imgSwap($scope.images); 
        $scope.displayImage = $scope.images.current;
        $scope.toggleValue = !$scope.toggleValue;
        console.log($scope.toggleValue);
      };

    },
    link:function(scope, element){
      scope.displayImage = scope.images.current;
    }
  }
});
```

but in my opinion instead of playing with a **toggleValue**, you'd better **transclude** the content and play with a show hide value

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I will try to change my approach. Thanks. Can't we make use of `this` like in `JavaScript`? Anyway thanks. I will try this.

Comment: you mean replacing $scope with this ? if so no you can't the scope is the glue between your view and your controller. the scope of the link and the controller function are the same but as in the controller it's injected you need to use the $scope name and in the link you can use whatever name you like but the first parameter is the scope.